# tic tac toe python-turtle alternating x and o

Tags: python, python-turtle

i am making a tic tac toe game for a school and over in the function clicked I am trying to make it see if there is an empty space in the board if there is, it can go on with placing the x or o and if its not it will print the place if full to stop the user drawing a O over and X or the other way around , instead it keeps saying the place is full even if its not and it wont alternate between x and o

```
#cross
board =["","","","","","","","",""]
nextturn = "x" 
def draw_x_o(board):
    x=-300
    y=300
    for stuff in board:
        if stuff=="x":
            x_draw(x, y)
        elif stuff=="o":
            o_draw(x, y)
        else:
            print("nothing here")
        x=x+200
        if x >100:
            x=-300
            y=y-200
def clicked(x, y):
    global board, nextturn
    colum=(300+x)//200
    row=(-y+300 )//200
    square=colum + row*3
    square= int(square)
    print("you clicked",x,",",y,"square",square)
    board[square]= nextturn
    if board[square]=="": 
        if nextturn=="x":
            nextturn="o"
        elif nextturn=="o":
            nextturn="x"
    else:
        print("the place is full")
    draw_x_o(board)
onscreenclick(clicked)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be way easier to read of you used a list of int list for your board : 0 if it's empty, 1 for a cross and 2 for a round for example.

```py
board = [[0]*3]*3 
print(board[0][2] )  # print the top right case, you can access to any
# case with board[y][x] and it allows you to print
# your board in the console with :
sign = [' ', 'x', 'o']
for l in board:
     print(*(sign[i] for i in l))
```

Comment: i am extremely confused wouldn't board[0][2] give an error since there is only 1 variable wich is 0

Comment: Board as I intialized it is [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] ; it's a list of list of len 3

Comment: Nevermind I miswrite it I edited my answer with the good synthax, sorry